# ¿Es correcto decir "hay mucho viento afuera"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, tiempo-meteorológico, haber

Esa expresión me resulta incómoda, como si fuera incorrecta aunque no sabría decir porqué. Me parece que el problema es "hay" uno no dice "afuera hay lluvia".

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Está bien que no sepas por qué te resulta incómoda, pero ¿podrías especificar la parte concreta que te resulta incómoda? ¿Es tal vez el uso de "afuera"? ¿Es el uso de "hay"?

Comment: Hola Sime. Tal y como comenta @CarlosAlejo , por favor dale una vuelta a la pregunta. ¿Qué te incomoda de ella? ¿En qué contexto la has visto? Lee [ask] para enfocar mejor la pregunta y luego dale a [edit] para consumar la mejora :)

Comment: Creo que sería mejor "hace much viento afuera."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según parece, tanto "hay viento" como "hace viento" [son correctas](https://www.saberespractico.com/ortografia-2/hace-viento-o-hay-viento/). Por mi parte, no encuentro nada raro en las construcciones con *haber*, que de hecho me resultan un poco más naturales que con *hacer*. Sospecho que hay diferencias que tienen que ver con el uso de *viento* o *lluvia* como condiciones meteorológicas (a la par de *frío* o *calor*) o bien como eventos puntuales (generalmente con artículo indefinido).

Como eventos puntuales, *haber* suena correcto y se puede reemplazar por un verbo asociado al evento:

> Hay un viento que vuela todo. = "Sopla un viento que..."
>   Hay un vientito bastante frío. = "Está soplando un vientito..."
>   Hay una lluvia ligera. = "Cae una lluvia ligera."

Con *hacer*, como dije, me surge una construcción similar a la que usaría para hablar de frío o calor.

> Hace mucho viento afuera. = "Está muy ventoso afuera."
>   Hace una lluvia fuerte. = "Está lloviendo fuerte."

Tanto con *lluvia* como con *viento* creo que es mucho más habitual usar *haber*, ya que las ocasiones en que se puede usar *hacer* son más restringidas (porque hablando del clima, *hacer* sugiere que debe seguir un adjetivo).